# Writing a script having if else condition using painless in elasticswearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a script as follows

```
if (ctx._source.event.isKeyEntity != null) 
{
    if (ctx._source.event.isKeyEntity == 0) 
    {
        ctx._source.event.isKeyEntity = false;
    } 
    else if (ctx._source.event.isKeyEntity == 1) 
    {
        ctx._source.event.isKeyEntity = true;
    }
}
```

But i keep on getting some error ot the other.

I am not able to understand pianless scripting language properly.

Can someone please help??

Comment: It would help if you show us what errors you're getting.

Comment: What work do you want to do?
Do you want to replace any value of 1 and 0 to true and false respectively of a field named "event" ?